# writing function for trigonometric angle

Tags: python, trigonometry

I have used a for loop using python (0,10000,1). `'i'` represents the angle. But my concern is that the value of the angle exceeds more than 360 degree. I would like to limit my value within the range of 0-360 degrees. If my angle goes to 361 degree it will be 1 degree and so on. Here is my sample code to generate values but not sure how to keep it within the limit.

```
i=0 #angle
i_all=[] #list of angles
for j in range (0,10000,1):
    i=j
    i_all.append(i)
    
print (i_all)
```

Comment: @EdwardKhachatryan I need something where the for loop exist and it cannot be changed. I need to know only the way to keep my i value within 0-360.

Comment: Please change your shown code to reflect that side-requirement. I.e. show what "something else" the loop needs to be "attached with".

Comment: @Yunnosch I already get my answer from below. Shall I upload the whole code and explain everything according to my code?

Comment: How about making a [mcve] which demonstrates all aspects of what you need? Python has so many ways of doing things efficiently, that I expect a better solution the more precisely you ask for what you really need. So no, not "whole code" and not "explain everything", just "complete" like "all relevant information". By only showing your loop idea, you restrict the solutions to that narrow subset of Pythons power. That way you run the risk of not getting your XY-problem spotted and cleanly solved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: As you can see in comments, your question was not clear enough on your side requirements and you had to clarify "No, not like that, for reasons." If you explain the reasons, instead of filtering among all the many answer those which do not fit those unspecified reasons, you could get much more creative solutions. - And just possibly get some undownvotes or upvotes.

Comment: @Yunnosch ohh thanks. I got it.

Comment: Do not get me wrong, showing your coding attempt is GOOD. Do not try to make your question more open for solutions by deleting your own attempts. But add something to make the foundation for solutoins and to illustrate your design decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use modulo:

```
i = j % 360
```

So your code becomes

```
i=0 #angle
i_all=[] #list of angles
for j in range (0,10000,1):
    i=j%360
    i_all.append(i)

print (i_all)
```

Comment: ohh thanks..I really forget about that basic things. It helps.

Comment: List comprehension makes this even easier `i_all = [i % 360 for i in range(0, 10000, 1)]`

Comment: @OliverRadini I cannot use list comprehension as my for loop is attached with something else. For the sake of simplicity I have written the code above.